# Cómo ajustar la altura del eje y-axis de un grafico de barras en React, La libreria highchart

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, next.js

Este es mi gráfico cuando tengo una cantidad de datos, quisiera saber como puedo ajustar el tamaño del eje Y-axis según la información que llegue.

Configuración general del eje Y-axis:

```
yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: null,
    },
    tickPositions: null,
    stackLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      formatter() {
        return `<span class="text-numeric">${quantityToThousands(
          this.total,
        )}</span> €`;
      },
    },
    labels: {
      formatter() {
        return `<span class="text-numeric">${quantityToThousands(
          this.value,
        )}</span> €`;
      },
    },
  }
```

y este es un fragmento de código del componente final, donde creo que puedo obtener la cantidad de proyectos que viene, y según ese dato aumentar la altura Y-axis:

```
const getOptions = () => {
    ProjectsOverviewGraphOptions.series = series;
    ProjectsOverviewGraphOptions.xAxis.categories = xAxis;
    ProjectsOverviewGraphOptions.yAxis.tickPositions = ticks;

    return ProjectsOverviewGraphOptions;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    prepareProjectsDataToShow();
  }, []);

  return series === null || xAxis === null || ticks === null ? (
    <p>Cargando....</p>
  ) : (
    <div className='text-center'>
      <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={getOptions()} />
      <div className='pt-0'>
        <small className='text-muted'>
          * Pendientes: solicitudes activas, en borrador, en revisión y
          presupuesto no asignado
        </small>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

**[image: texto en negrita]**